# How to use TypeHandler for INSERT statements in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

There is configuration:

```
<resultMap id="mapId" type="package.MyType">
    <result property="prop1" column="column1" />
    <result property="prop2" column="column2" />
    <result property="prop3" column="column3" typeHandler="package.MyTypeHandler" />
</resultMap>

<select id="selectStat" resultMap="mapId">
    SELECT `column1`, `column2`, `column3` 
    FROM `table`; 
</select>
```

For select statement all is fine, handler is invoked.

How can i write INSERT statement to invoke the same handler for column3 when inserting data?

Answer (score 13):

You can use INSERT statement as follows.

```
<insert parameterType='myType' >
  INSERT into table(column1, column2, column3) values(#{prop1},#{prop2},#{prop3,typeHandler=package.Typehandler})
</insert>
```

**Edit** : use `typeHandler=` and not `typehandler=`

Comment: The correct syntax is `typeHandler=` rather than `typehandler=`